# awk multiple conditional command

Tags: unix, awk

I am trying to select some strings with awk but i am not getting exactly what i want

the data i have is in a column like this

```
name1    condition1
name2    condition2/condition1
name3    CONDITION3
name4    condition1/condition4
name5    CND1
name6    condition6
name7    cnd1
name8    condition3/cnd1
name9    CND1/condition2
```

I am trying to pick condition1 and cnd1 regardless its position and case of the letters.

I want the output to be like (condition1 and cnd1 in combination with anything)

```
name2    condition2/condition1
name4    condition1/condition4
name8    condition3/cnd1
name9    CND1/condition2
```

and another output to look like (condition1 and cnd1 ALONE)

```
name1    condition1
name5    CND1
name7    cnd1
```

I am using this command

```
awk 'BEGIN{IGNORECASE=1} $2 ~ /^cnd1$/ || /^condition1$/'  directory/file.tab
```

this command is eliminating all the combinations.

How do I form the right command for this?

Answer (score 3):

You need to repeat the `$2 ~` in the second part of the `||` expression.

```
awk 'BEGIN{IGNORECASE=1} $2 ~ /^cnd1$/ || $2 ~ /^condition1$/'
```

Or use the regex `|` operator:

```
awk 'BEGIN{IGNORECASE=1} $2 ~ /^(cnd|condition)1$/'
```

For the first case, condition1 and cnd1 in combination with anything, try this:

```
awk 'BEGIN{IGNORECASE=1} $2 ~ /(cnd|condition)1/ && $2 ~ "/"'
```

Comment: sweet! thanks John, the second part of my question is solved. do you know what command i can use to get the combinations? i can't really find the right expression to tell this to the Linux! (note that i am trying to get teh combinations without the "condition1 or cnd1")

Comment: Hello John, i have unticked the answer because i went again throught the  data.... name by name and i found these some problems: 1- some of the condition1 - condition3 are separated by a space and sometimes by a (-). so the only solution i find for this trouble is to say (excuse me i am going to say this in english!) "search through the column, exclude "^cnd1$","^condition1$" (alone) regardless the case and exclude anything that DOESN'T contain the strings "cnd1" and condition1 regardless the case. I think this is going to be a long command, but it is my only way out of this. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you're writing to files, you can do it in one pass:

```
awk '
    BEGIN {IGNORECASE=1} 
    $2 ~ /\<(cnd|condition)1\>/ {
        if ($2 ~ /\//)
            print > combined_cnd1
        else
            print > only_cnd1
    }
'
```

Note the use of word boundaries `\<` and `\>` to prevent false matching for things like "ACND1" and "condition11"

Comment: Thanks foe the conditioned statement

Comment: just be aware that IGNORECASE is GNU-awk specific. You can get rid of the BEGIN section and just test `tolower($2)` if you'd like to remove that restriction. Not sure which awks support \< and \> but it won't be all of them, though GNU awk does so all is well as long as you stick with gawk.